# how to read value from UITextFiled

Tags: iphone

i am making a temperature converter as iphone application can someone help me that how can i read a value entered in textfield of iphone through keyboard for conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get text from text field as -

```
NSString *str = [txtField text];
```

Comment: can it also be used for entering int and float type numbers

Comment: actually what user enter is can only be get in a NSString and then you can convert it by using this int i = [str intValue]; -- float f = [str floatValue];

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtField.text];
```

Or

`NSString *str = txtField.text`;

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str=textFild.text
int x = [str intValue];
```

Then use this value for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You Connect text field with the IBOutlet variable via nib. Then you can access the value in the text field using txtField.text